# How to ensure gae memcache results are same in post method as in get method

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

For the get method, a list is generated from memcache.

For the post method, the user chooses a post from the list from memcache and does something to it. (I retrieve the memcache list again.) How do I make sure that the memcache list retrieved for post is the same as the one retrieved for get?

The situation I'm worried about is another user submitting a new post and changing the memcache right before the post method is run.

code:

```
    def get(self):
        sells = memcache.get("SELLS")

        if sells is None:
            *do some stuff*

        else:
            logging.error("OFFERS IN MC")
            sells.sort(key = lambda x:x.price)
            count = 1

        self.render("buy.html", sells = sells, count = count)

    def post(self):
        first_name = self.request.get('first_name')
        num = int(self.request.get('num')) 

        if first_name and num:
            sells = memcache.get("SELLS")

            *do some stuff*

            self.redirect('/contact?first_name=' + first_name + "&amount=" + amount + "&price=" + price)
        else: 
            cart_error = "fill in all the boxes"
            self.render("buy.html", cart_error = cart_error, sells = list(sells))
```

Comment: for the reasons @themaestro wrote in his post, you should try to pass the parameters you need into the POST parameters when the submit button is clicked by the user in _buy.html_

Comment: @tunedconsulting I'm not sure how to directly transfer the parameters from the get method to the post method without querying for them again

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `gets` and `cas` methods that are part of the client object. 
See: [GAE Memecache Reference](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass)

I'm not entirely clear on what exactly is necessary in your case though. Is the flow you're worried about supposed to be:
1) User in get request gets to see a list of options
2) He then selects one of those options in the post
If this is the case, just using gets and cas won't do it since you need to track the object across requests, so you could try saving another variable in memcache that tracks when the list was last updated and also send that variable into the browser, so when the user posts you check the value from the browser with the value currently in memcache. If they're different, you know an update occurred.

A different, but also problematic case might be:
1) User in get request looks at the list
2) User selects one of those options in the post
3) Simultaneously another user selects the same option
And with that you'll have yourself a nice little race position. In this case, the gets, cas model works really well, since it will only let you update the object if somebody else didn't touch it.

My guess is you actually want to handle both of these potential cases. Race conditions are a bitch, what can I say.